# Order of operations vs speed

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, data-science

I have been thinking about the performance of some queries on Bigquery and was wondering if the order of functions makes a difference.

For example, which of the following columns executes faster:

MIN(CAST(timestamp_col AS DATE))

or

CAST(MIN(timestamp_col) AS DATE)

My intuition tells me that the latter would be faster because the cast operation is done only once. But, I don't see a performance gain. In fact, I see a performance drop.

Comment: It is probably dependent on data types and # of records.  In your example, it is probably quicker to sort dates than timestamps (timestamps have hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds to compare in addition to the year, month, and day that dates would need) , so the overhead of casting everything might make the sorting faster

Comment: I tried running the queries with the chicago_taxi_trips public dataset and the second query consumed less [slot](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots) time. Could you confirm the volume of the data and whether you are using it inside a select statement or in some where condition. To replicate your scenario further could you provide the query & sample data.